# Trouble connecting to Teradata with teradata python module

Tags: python, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

I have installed ODBC and done pip install teradata, but

After trying to connect to teradata session, I get this error:

```
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, u'[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Could not find security entry point')
```

Here is what my python script looks like:

```
 import teradata


udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName = 'table1', version='1.0', logConsole = False)

session = udaExec.connect(method = "odbc", system = "db1", username = "user1", password = "pass1", driver = "Teradata")
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it had to do with security issues within my terminal settings. Simple fix by using an IDE.